# Declaring generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with defining generics in static methods and fields.

Suppose I have a simple interface, used by all classes that contains a field of type `T` called `value`:

```
public interface HasValue<T> {
    // Getter:
    public T value();
    // Setter:
    public void setValue(T value);
}
```

If I have an array of object of a type `N` that implements `HasValue<T>`, I may have necessity to order this array. One classical way is to compare those `N` objects using their `value` field: if `T` implements the `Comparable<T>` interface and both `arg0` and `arg1` are of type N, then `arg0.compareTo(arg1)` will be equal to `arg0.value().compareTo(arg1.value())`.

The goal is to create a usable, not time-consuming, possible simple way to obtain the aforementioned situation.

---

A possibility would be to create a custom `Comparator<N>` every time I need something similar. That would force me to write code each time: definitly time consuming.

---

I could create that `Comparator<N>` directly in the interface. The first try is to create a method:

1. It needs to be a default method. Part of the code will test if the class `T` implements the `Comparable` interface or not, and for that I need an example of the `T` class: using `this.value().getClass()` is the fastest way. With a static method I could not use `this`.
2. I need to explicitate that the `N` class implements the interface `HasValue<T>`, otherwise the computer will not know.

   ```
   public default <N extends HasValue<T>> Comparator<N> COMPARE_BY_VALUE() throws Exception{
       if(Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(this.value().getClass()))
           return new Comparator<N>() {
                           public int compare(N arg0, N arg1) {
                               Comparable value0 = (Comparable) arg0.value(), 
                                   value1 = (Comparable) arg1.value();
                               return value0.compareTo(value1);
                           }
           };
       else throw new Exception("The class of the value does not implement the interface Comparable.\n");
   }
   ```

   - This strategy works... barely. It's clumsy, involves rawtypes, creates the `Comparator<N>` every time.

---

Second try: creating a static **field**.

- The strategy is to separate the testing problem from the rest. A default method will do the test: in case of success the method will return a static `Comparator`, otherwise an exception.

  ```
  public default <N extends HasValue<T>> Comparator<?> COMPARE_BY_VALUE() throws Exception{
      if(Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(this.value().getClass()))
          return COMPARE_BY_VALUE;
      else throw new Exception("The class of the value does not implement the interface Comparable.\n");
  }
  public static Comparator<HasValue> COMPARE_BY_VALUE = new Comparator() {
              public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
                  Comparable value0 = (Comparable) ((HasValue)arg0).value(), 
                      value1 = (Comparable) ((HasValue)arg1).value();
                  return value0.compareTo(value1);
              }
          };
  ```
- While declaring the static field I (unfortunately) cannot state something like `public static <T, N extends HasValue<T>> Comparator<N> COMPARE_BY_VALUE`. That forces me to return a `Comparator<HasValue>`: not what I wanted.
- Using wildcards I can obtain something *close*:

  ```
      public default <N extends HasValue<T>> Comparator<?> COMPARE_BY_VALUE() throws Exception{
          if(Confrontable.class.isAssignableFrom(this.value().getClass()))
              return COMPARE_BY_VALUE;
          else throw new Exception("The class of the value does not implement the interface Comparable.\n");
      }
      public static Comparator<? extends HasValue<? extends Comparable<?>>> COMPARE_BY_VALUE 
              = new Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
              Comparable value0 = (Confrontable) ((HasValue<?>)arg0).value(), value1 = (Confrontable) ((HasValue<?>)arg1).value();
              return value0.compareTo(value1);
          }
      };
  ```
- This modification will return (in theory) a `Comparator<N>` where `N` extends `HasValue<T>`, `T` extends `Comparable<U>` and `U` is actually `T`.

  - That because every `?` in `Comparator<? extends HasValue<? extends Comparable<?>>>` is interpreted by the JVM as a potential new class: three `?` means three new class (`N`, `T` and `U`), and it happens that `T` implements `Comparable<T>` - thus `U` and `T` are one and the same.
- I still have a great amount of rawtypes...
- ...but at least I have only *one* `Comparator` for each `N` and `T`.

---

Now, while the last strategy seems to works, I would like to know if there is a better way to obtain my goal.
My initial idea was to state something like

```
     public static <T extends Comparable<T>, N extends HasValue<T>> Comparator<N> COMPARE_BY_VALUE = new Comparator() {
                public int compare(N arg0, N arg1) {
                    return arg0.value().compareTo(arg1.value());
                }
        };
```

and obtain a `Comparator<N>` without wildcars. This however sends all types of errors. Someone has an idea?

Comment: In Java 8 if you want to easily get a comparator that compares using a particular field you can use [`Comparator.comparing(ClassName::getThing)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: What is the benefit you are gaining by using generics in this example?  Why not just public interface HasValue{...}? Why is such a broad interface needed in the first place? What would be a real life example of where this implementation would be beneficial?

Comment: Why not extending `Comparable` directly on `HasValue` ?

Comment: @dotvav : Because `N` implementing `HasValue<T>` doesn't imply that `T` will <i>always</i> implement `Comparable`: `T` can be everything.

Comment: @John : An easy and quite frequent real-life possibility would be any program that needs two or more different data structures. The data structures are of different classes, each data structure uses nodes of a different class from the others, but all nodes have a field called `value`. Using the interface `HasValue<T>` allows to create a **standard way** to access the `value`... instead that going crazy with a different method calling for each node class. It makes updating easier, too.

Comment: I'm thinking you might be over thinking this.  "Data structures of different classes" is not a specific example.  A specific example would illustrate the value of what you are trying to achieve with the addition of this interface that uses generics.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to illustrate the value of using interfaces I could say something like: For  example if I have an interface called Greeter and greeter had a method called getSalutation() I could create classes that implemented greater such as Cow, Pig, Dog etc.  Then, given a collection of Greeters I could iterate through the collection, call getSalution() and get something like "Moo", "Oink", "Bow-Wow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<HasValue<T>> createValueComparator() {
    return new Comparator<HasValue<T>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(HasValue<T> o1, HasValue<T> o2) {
            return o1.value().compareTo(o2.value());
        }
    };
}
```

This reads: for every type `T` which implements `Comparable` this method returns comparator which can compare `HasValue<T>`.

Java might not be able to properly infer types in such convoluted constructs. You might have to add the types explicitly:

```
Collections.sort(list, Main.<Integer> createValueComparator());
```

or:

```
Comparator<HasValue<Integer>> comparator = createValueComparator();
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Keep in mind that a lot of programmers overuse generics. Usually there is a simpler way to achieve the same - while still maintaining type safety.